# Compare elements of two arrays php

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, strpos

So I have two arrays:

```
$badwords = array('bad-word', 'some-racist-term', 'nasty', 'bad-language');

$inputphrases = array('this-is-sentence-with-bad-word', 'nothing-bad-here', 'more-clean-stuff', 'this-is-nasty', 'this-contains-some-racist-term', 'one-more-clean', 'clean-clean', 'contains-bad-language');
```

I need to compare elements of input phrases array with bad words array and output new array with phrases WITHOUT bad words like this:

```
$outputarray = array('nothing-bad-here', 'more-clean-stuff','one-more-clean', 'clean-clean');
```

I tried doing this with two foreach loops but it gives me opposite result, aka it outputs phrases WITH bad words.
Here is code I tried that outputs opposite result:

```
function letsCompare($inputphrases, $badwords)
{
    foreach ($inputphrases as $inputphrase) {

        foreach ($badwords as $badword) {

            if (strpos(strtolower(str_replace('-', '', $inputphrase)), strtolower(str_replace('-', '', $badword))) !== false) {
                $result[] = ($inputphrase);

            }
        }
    }
return $result;
}

$result = letsCompare($inputphrases, $badwords);
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is not a clean solution, but hope, you'll got what is going on. do not hesitate to ask for clearence. [repl.it link](https://repl.it/HJbW)

```
$inputphrases = array('this-is-sentence-with-bad-word', 'nothing-bad-here', 'more-clean-stuff', 'this-is-nasty', 'this-contains-some-racist-term', 'one-more-clean', 'clean-clean', 'contains-bad-language');


$new_arr = array_filter($inputphrases, function($phrase) {
  $badwords = array('bad-word', 'some-racist-term', 'nasty', 'bad-language');
  $c = count($badwords);
  for($i=0; $i<$c; $i++) {
    if(strpos($phrase, $badwords[$i]) !== false){
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
});

print_r($new_arr);
```

Comment: At first it seems like its working fine, but for some reason it just nor working with a lot of queries. For example with added bad word john-day-yahweh and input phrase john-day-yahweh-bro it will not work. see here:
https://repl.it/HJbW/2
P.S. I need strtolower and str_replace because some phrases in arrays are in capital and some with dash, some without. Appreciate your help

Comment: that was a classic 0, false confusion of php -)) updated answer, also fixed repl.it snippet https://repl.it/HJbW/3